# I used jssor slider 17.0 v and I need to set the slider height and width based on window size not fixed size

Tags: jssor

I used jssor slider v 17.0.

Slider height and width are set based on window size but not fixed sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove responsive code.

Look for the following code and remove it,

```
//responsive code begin
function ScaleSlider(...
...
//responsive code end
```

Comment: i removed function ScaleSlider() but it is not working.

Comment: remove all code between //responsive code begin and //responsive code end